# Web2py Scheduler is creating "Idle in Transaction" process with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, scheduler, web2py, web2py-modules

This question is specific to scheduler in Web2py Framework.

I am using scheduler as a Linux Service.

I created a file /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Web2Py scheduler service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -K myApp
Type=simple
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then install the service calling:

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched.service 

systemctl start /etc/systemd/system/web2py-sched
```

When I checked my Postgres status, I see there are processes with "Idle in Transaction" status.

```
may@myApp:/home/www-data/web2py/scmyAppts$ sudo systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main
● postgresql@9.5-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-10-16 15:39:25 PDT; 1 weeks 1 days ago
 Main PID: 28202 (postgres)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@9.5-main.service
           ├─10956 postgres: may mydb ::1(60654) idle in transaction                                                                           
           ├─10957 postgres: may mydb ::1(60656) idle in transaction                                                                           
           ├─13421 postgres: may mydb 10.5.77.35(51998) idle                                                                                   
           ├─13422 postgres: may mydb 10.5.77.35(52004) idle                                                                                   
           ├─13423 postgres: may postgres 10.5.77.35(52005) idle                                                                               
           ├─13425 postgres: may mydb 10.5.77.35(52007) idle                                                                                   
           ├─13433 postgres: may mydb 10.5.77.35(52332) idle                                                                                   
           ├─28202 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
           ├─28204 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
           ├─28205 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
           ├─28206 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
           ├─28207 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
           ├─28208 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
           ├─30475 postgres: may mydb ::1(59838) idle                                                                                          
           ├─30476 postgres: may mydb ::1(59840) idle in transaction                                                                           
           └─30500 postgres: may mydb ::1(59842) idle
```

When I observed few of process are idle and transaction and my DB Queries are timing out, I checked to see which table is acquiring locks.

```
SELECT relation, pid, mode, granted, relname
FROM pg_locks
INNER JOIN pg_stat_user_tables
ON pg_locks.relation = pg_stat_user_tables.relid
WHERE pg_locks.pid='30476';

relation    pid    mode            granted   relname
16553      30476  AccessShareLock   TRUE    scheduler_task
```

Please help me on this, I have thoroughly gone thru my scheduler code and there is db.commit() called after every transaction.

Version:

```
Version
2.17.2-stable+timestamp.2018.10.06.18.54.02
(Running on nginx/1.10.3, Python 2.7.12)

web2py is up to date
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your app really called 'myApp' as you configured by the service start `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -K myApp`?

You have to specify your application by name. 'myapp' is just a placeholder.

Best regards Clemens

Comment: Yes its myApp :) only.

Comment: Would it be possible that you send me an extract of your application (relevant controllers and view), thus I can import it in my environment, which is also web2py+nginx+postgres. Because I have no problems with the scheduler. Maybe your  uWSGI problem can be clarified too ;-)